# TRIGGER For points summing

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, summary

In my table Team which contains:

- Name
- Wins
- Draws
- Losses
- Points

Now i want to do a trigger which sum wins, draws, losses and puts it into points column.
Win * 3, Draw * 1, loss * 0

I did something like that:

```
create or replace 
trigger Summ_points
AFTER insert ON  Team
FOR EACH ROW 
ENABLE
DECLARE
tmp Team.Points%type;
BEGIN
    select sum(Wins*3 + Draws + Losses*0) into tmp from Team;
    Update Team
    set Points=tmp;
END Summ_points;
```

but it does not work, because all records are updated :/

Language: PL SQl , Oracle

Comment: It is forbidden to execute a query on the triggered table inside the trigger. Inside teh trigger you can access and modify only the triggered record and only using :NEW and :OLD references.
So if you want to update all records of the table inside a trigger on the same table, this is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside teh trigger you can access and modify only the triggered record and only using :NEW and :OLD references.

Here's how to update a field on the triggered record of the table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sum_points
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON team
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :NEW.Points := :NEW.Wins * 3 + :NEW.Draws;
END;
```

Comment: I corrected the answer basing on suggestions received

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
create or replace 
trigger Summ_points
BEFORE insert ON  Team
FOR EACH ROW 
ENABLE
BEGIN
    SELECT (:new.Wins*3 + :new.Draws + :new.Losses*0) into :new.Points 
    FROM dual;
END Summ_points;
```

This adds the points in each row.  I'm not sure why you would need to add points from multiple rows.